# Getting array elements with valueForKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

Is there any way to access an `NSArray` element with `valueForKeyPath`?  Google's reverse geocoder service, for example, returns a very complex data structure.  If I want to get the city, right now I have to break it into two calls, like this:

```
NSDictionary *address = [NSString stringWithString:[[[dictionary objectForKey:@"Placemark"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [address valueForKeyPath:@"AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.SubAdministrativeArea.Locality.LocalityName"]);
```

Just wondering if there's a way to shoehorn the `objectAtIndex:` call into the `valueForKeyPath` string.  I tried a javascript-esque formulation like @"Placemark[0].address" but no dice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The full documentation for what's allowed using Key-Value Coding is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/). There are not, to my knowledge, any operators that allow you to grab a particular array or set object.

Comment: You can grab a particular array. Not sure about getting an array element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework

Comment: Please update the link in this answer, the page no longer exists.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a category I just wrote for NSObject that can handle array indexes  so you can access a nested object like this: "person.friends[0].name"

```
@interface NSObject (ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes)
   -(id)valueForKeyPathWithIndexes:(NSString*)fullPath;
@end


#import "NSObject+ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes.h"    
@implementation NSObject (ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes)

-(id)valueForKeyPathWithIndexes:(NSString*)fullPath
{
    NSRange testrange = [fullPath rangeOfString:@"["];
    if (testrange.location == NSNotFound)
        return [self valueForKeyPath:fullPath];

    NSArray* parts = [fullPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    id currentObj = self;
    for (NSString* part in parts)
    {
        NSRange range1 = [part rangeOfString:@"["];
        if (range1.location == NSNotFound)          
        {
            currentObj = [currentObj valueForKey:part];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString* arrayKey = [part substringToIndex:range1.location];
            int index = [[[part substringToIndex:part.length-1] substringFromIndex:range1.location+1] intValue];
            currentObj = [[currentObj valueForKey:arrayKey] objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    return currentObj;
}
@end
```

Use it like so

```
NSString* personsFriendsName = [obj valueForKeyPathsWithIndexes:@"me.friends[0].name"];
```

There's no error checking, so it's prone to breaking but you get the idea.

Comment: Kind of irrelevant now that we have the improved Obj-C literal syntax. You can write the original statement in my question as `NSDictionary *address = dictionary[@"Placemark"][0][@"address"];`

Comment: Yea the new syntax is great. I'm using my example above in a scenario where an external data structure may change, so a string selector is very helpful.

Comment: @jsd It may still sometimes be useful when used with Cocoa Bindings or with operators such as `@sum`. Especially when used with temporary, debug labels.

Comment: I modified the above code slightly to allow for named indexes similar to XPATH in XML so you can use @"me.friends[@name="Dave"].address"

Comment: @nh32rg anyone home?  wanna update the code on this page with yours?

Comment: It's still relevant, especially if you want to save the location (the key path) as a string and use it later.

Answer (score 3):

You can intercept the keypath in the object holding the NSArray.

In your case the keypath would become Placemark0.address... Override valueForUndefinedKey; look for the index in the keypath;  something like this:

```
-(id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // Handle paths like Placemark0, Placemark1, ...
    if ([key hasPrefix:@"Placemark"])
    {
        // Caller wants to access the Placemark array.
        // Find the array index they're after.
        NSString *indexString = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Placemark" withString:@""];
        NSInteger index = [indexString integerValue];

        // Return array element.
        if (index < self.placemarks.count)
            return self.placemarks[index];
    }

    return [super valueForUndefinedKey:key];
}
```

This works really well for model frameworks e.g. [Mantle](https://github.com/blog/1299-mantle-a-model-framework-for-objective-c).

Comment: `valueForUndefinedKey` is never called in practice.

Answer (score 0):

### Subclass NSArrayController or NSDictionaryController

Use `NSArrayController` for this purpose, because `NSObjectController` does not include `NSArrayController`'s provided handling of changes to bound array elements. If you use this same code with `NSObjectController` instead, then using Cocoa Bindings with your `NSObjectController` instance will only set the (bound interface element's) value at the time of binding but will not receive the messages from array elements in return. By using `NSObjectController` for this purpose, the user interface will not continue to update even though the `contentObject` is updated. Simply use the same code with `NSArrayController` to also include proper support for arrays -- which is the matter at hand.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface DelvingArrayController : NSArrayController
@end
```

---

```
#import "DelvingArrayController.h"
@implementation DelvingArrayController
-(id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(.+?)\\[(\\d+?)\\]$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSArray<NSString*> *components = [keyPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    id currentObject = self;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < components.count; i++)
    {
        if (![components[i] isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            NSTextCheckingResult *check_result = [regex firstMatchInString:components[i] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, components[i].length)];
            if (!check_result)
                currentObject = [currentObject valueForKey:components[i]];
            else
            {
                NSRange array_name_capture_range = [check_result rangeAtIndex:1];
                NSRange number_capture_range = [check_result rangeAtIndex:2];
                if (number_capture_range.location == NSNotFound)
                    currentObject = [currentObject valueForKey:components[i]];
                else if (array_name_capture_range.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSString *array_name = [components[i] substringWithRange:array_name_capture_range];
                    NSUInteger array_index = [[components[i] substringWithRange:number_capture_range] integerValue];
                    currentObject = [currentObject valueForKey:array_name];
                    if ([currentObject count] > array_index)
                        currentObject = [currentObject objectAtIndex:array_index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return currentObject;
}
//at some point... also override setValueForKeyPath :-)
@end
```

This code uses `NSRegularExpression`, which is for macOS 10.7+.
I leave it as an exercise for you to use the same approach to also override `setValueForKeyPath`, if you want write functionality.

---

### Cocoa Bindings Example Usage

Say we want a little trivia game, with a window that shows a question and uses four buttons to display multiple-choice options. We have the questions and multiple-choice options as `NSString`s in a plist, and also an `NSNumber` or optionally `BOOL` entries to indicate the correct answers. **We want to bind the option buttons to options in the array, for each question also stored in an array.**

Here is the example plist containing some trivia questions related to the game *Halo*. Notice that the options are located within nested arrays.

[image: Trivia Property List]

In this example, I use `NSObjectController *stringsController` as the controller for the entire plist file, and `DelvingArrayController *triviaController` as the controller for the trivia-related plist entries. You might simply use one `DelvingArrayController` instead, but I provide this for your understanding.

The trivia window is really simple, so I merely design it using Interface Builder in MainMenu.xib:

[image: Trivia Window in Interface Builder]

[image: Trivia Interface Builder Bindings]

A subclass of `NSDocumentController` is used for showing the trivia window via an `NSMenuItem` added in Interface Builder. The instance of this subclass is also in the .xib, so if we want to use the interface elements in the .xib, we have to wait for the Application Delegate instance's `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method or otherwise wait until the .xib has finished loading...

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "MenuInterfaceDocumentController.h"
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property IBOutlet MenuInterfaceDocumentController *PrimaryInterfaceController;
@end
```

---

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize PrimaryInterfaceController;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if ([NSApp mainMenu])
    {
        [PrimaryInterfaceController configureTriviaWindow];
    }
}
```

---

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface MenuInterfaceDocumentController : NSDocumentController
{
    IBOutlet NSMenuItem *MenuItemTrivia;    // shows the Trivia window
    IBOutlet NSWindow *TriviaWindow;
    IBOutlet NSTextView *TriviaQuestionField;
    IBOutlet NSButton *TriviaOption1, *TriviaOption2, *TriviaOption3, *TriviaOption4;
}
@property NSObjectController *stringsController;
-(void)configureTriviaWindow;
@end
```

---

```
#import "MenuInterfaceDocumentController.h"
@interface MenuInterfaceDocumentController ()
@property NSDictionary *languageDictionary;
@property DelvingArrayController *triviaController;
@property NSNumber *triviaAnswer;
@end

@implementation MenuInterfaceDocumentController
@synthesize stringsController, languageDictionary, triviaController, triviaAnswer;
// all this happens before the MainMenu is available, and before the AppDelegate is sent applicationDidFinishLaunching
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        if (!stringsController)
            stringsController = [NSObjectController new];
        stringsController.editable = NO;
        // check for the plist file, eventually applying the following
        languageDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"plist"]];
        if (languageDictionary)
            [stringsController setContent:languageDictionary];
        if (!triviaController)
        {
            triviaController = [DelvingArrayController new];
            [triviaController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:stringsController withKeyPath:@"selection.trivia" options:nil];
        }
        triviaController.editable = NO;
        if (!triviaAnswer)
        {
            triviaAnswer = @0;
            [self bind:@"triviaAnswer" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.answer" options:nil];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
// if we ever do something like change the plist file to a duplicate plist file that is in a different language, use this kind of approach to keep the same trivia entry active
-(IBAction)changeLanguage:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger triviaQIndex = triviaController.selectionIndex;
    if (sender == MenuItemEnglishLanguage)
    {
        if ([self changeLanguageTo:@"en" Notify:YES])
        {
            [self updateSelectedLanguageMenuItemWithLanguageString:@"en"];
            if ([triviaController.content count] > triviaQIndex)    // in case the plist files don't match
                [triviaController setSelectionIndex:triviaQIndex];
        }
        else
            [self displayAlertFor:CUSTOM_ALERT_TYPE_LANGUAGE_CHANGE_FAILED];
    }
    else if (sender == MenuItemGermanLanguage)
    {
        if ([self changeLanguageTo:@"de" Notify:YES])
        {
            [self updateSelectedLanguageMenuItemWithLanguageString:@"de"];
            if ([triviaController.content count] > triviaQIndex)
                [triviaController setSelectionIndex:triviaQIndex];
        }
        else
            [self displayAlertFor:CUSTOM_ALERT_TYPE_LANGUAGE_CHANGE_FAILED];
    }
}
-(void)configureTriviaWindow
{
    [TriviaQuestionField bind:@"string" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.question" options:nil];
    [TriviaOption1 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[0]" options:nil];
    [TriviaOption2 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[1]" options:nil];
    [TriviaOption3 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[2]" options:nil];
    [TriviaOption4 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[3]" options:nil];
}
// this method is how you would manually set the value if you did not use binding:
-(void)updateTriviaAnswer
{
    triviaAnswer = [triviaController valueForKeyPath:@"selection.answer"];
}
-(IBAction)changeTriviaQuestion:(id)sender
{
    if (triviaController.selectionIndex >= [(NSArray*)triviaController.content count] - 1)
        [triviaController setSelectionIndex:0];
    else
        [triviaController setSelectionIndex:(triviaController.selectionIndex + 1)];
}
-(IBAction)showTriviaWindow:(id)sender
{
    [TriviaWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
}
- (IBAction)TriviaOptionChosen:(id)sender
{
    // tag integers 0 through 3 are assigned to the option buttons in Interface Builder
    if ([sender tag] == triviaAnswer.integerValue)
        [self changeTriviaQuestion:sender];
    else
        NSBeep();
}
@end
```

---

**Summary of Sequence**

```
NSObjectController *stringsController = [[NSObjectController alloc] initWithContent:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"plist"]]];
DelvingArrayController *triviaController = [DelvingArrayController new];
[triviaController bind:@"contentArray" toObject:stringsController withKeyPath:@"selection.trivia" options:nil];
NSNumber *triviaAnswer = @0;
[self bind:@"triviaAnswer" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.answer" options:nil];
// bind to .xib's interface elements after the nib has finished loading, else the IBOutlets are null
[TriviaQuestionField bind:@"string" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.question" options:nil];
[TriviaOption1 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[0]" options:nil];
[TriviaOption2 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[1]" options:nil];
[TriviaOption3 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[2]" options:nil];
[TriviaOption4 bind:@"title" toObject:triviaController withKeyPath:@"selection.options[3]" options:nil];
// when the user chooses the correct option, go to the next question
if ([sender tag] == triviaAnswer.integerValue)
{
    if (triviaController.selectionIndex >= [(NSArray*)triviaController.content count] - 1)
        [triviaController setSelectionIndex:0];
    else
        [triviaController setSelectionIndex:(triviaController.selectionIndex + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create methods that supports array for NSObject:

```
@interface NSObject(ArraySupported)
-(id)valueForKeySupportedArray:(NSString*)path;
-(id)valueForKeyPathSupportedArray:(NSString*)fullPath;
@end

@implementation NSObject(ArraySupported)
-(id)valueForKeySupportedArray:(NSString*)path {
    id value = nil;
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *array = (NSArray *)self;
        NSUInteger index = path.integerValue;
        if (index >= 0 && index < array.count) {
            value = array[index];
        }
    } else {
        value = [self valueForKey:path];
    }
    return value;
}

-(id)valueForKeyPathSupportedArray:(NSString*)fullPath {
    NSArray* parts = [fullPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    id value = self;
    for (NSString* part in parts) {
        value = [value valueForKeySupportedArray:part];
        if (value == nil) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
@end
```

How to use:

```
NSObject *object = @{@"Placemark":@[@{@"address":@"..."}]};
NSString *address = [object valueForKeyPathSupportedArray:@"Placemark.0.address"];
// address = "..."
```