# Parse nested JSON Object in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, json, nsmutablearray

Perhaps I am over-thinking or confusing myself, but my head is stuck in a loop over this and I cannot break out.

I have a a JSON of the format: (Validated at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

```
{
  id: 1,
  sections: "5",
  total: "10",
  result: {
    3: 00PM: [
      {
        name: "Anurag",
        status: "Web"
      },
      {
        name: "Anurag2",
        status: "Web2"
      }
    ],
    5: 00PM: [
      {
        name: "Anurag",
        status: "Seated"
      }
    ],
    6: 00PM: [
      {
        name: "Anurag4",
        status: "Web4"
      },
      {
        name: "Anurag5",
        status: "Web5"
      },
      {
        name: "Anurag6",
        status: "Web6"
      },
      {
        name: "Anurag7",
        status: "Web7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this so far:

```
        NSDictionary *dict = [response JSONValue];
        NSDictionary *results = [dict objectForKey:@"result"];

        NSInteger num_results = [[dict valueForKey:@"total"] intValue];
        NSInteger num_sections = [[dict valueForKey:@"sections"] intValue];

        NSMutableArray *sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:num_sections];
        NSMutableArray *objarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:num_results];
        NSMutableArray *obj= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:num_sections];
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:num_results];

        for (NSString* key in results) {
            NSLog(@"Key: %@", key); // prints out 3:00 PM...5:00 PM etc...
            [obj addObject:[results objectForKey:key]]; // nested objects within each key are saved in the array
            NSLog(@"Object 1: %@", obj);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < [obj count]; i++) {
            //NSLog(@"Object 2: %@", [obj objectAtIndex:i]);
            [temp addObject:[obj objectAtIndex:i]]; // I take each object from previous array and save it in a temp array
            for (int i = 0; i < num_results; i++) {
                NSLog(@"Object 3: %@", [temp objectAtIndex:i]);
                **[objarr addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:i]]; // I want to extract the object within the object but cannot get it to work**
            }   
        }
```

I am able to make an array of objects within each of the 3 keys inside results. But I am not able to get each of the objects inside them as a separate object and save them in an array.

For example, in an NSArray I have:

```
Object 3: (
        {
        name = "Anurag ";
        status = Web;
    },
        {
        name = "Anurag ";
        status = Web;
    }
)
```

How can I get the two objects inside this object and save them both in an array? 
I guess the main issue is I cannot refer to a key name to get the individual object.

Comment: Your "Object 3" is an array containing two dictionaries.

Comment: I think you are right. But how do I get its value? Inside object 3 I have two nested objects without keys.

Comment: Object 3 is an array (in fact, you created it) -- index it to get at the two dictionaries you put there.  (Or you could cut out the middleman and process the dictionaries you're getting out of `obj` immediately.)  (Hint:  Use more meaningful variable names, so you understand what you're doing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code,

```
NSDictionary *json = [response JSONValue];

// Get the objects you want
NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"result.6: 00PM"];
```

This will return an `NSArray` with the objects for the key **6: 00PM**

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework) too.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't know the value "6:00 PM". Thats why in my code I iterate over the entire results array using its index. That is not the issue though, I am able to extract that object. It is the nested objects within that object I need to get.

Comment: i think you need to get the `{
        name = "Anurag ";
        status = Web;
    }` and `{
        name = "Anurag ";
        status = Web;
    }` objects in an array, is it ?

Comment: Yes, all of them in a single array

Comment: my answer will give you the two objects of the Key `6:00PM` in an array. Same like **@"result.6: 00PM"** you need to use other keys, that will return corresponding arrays. At last you need to add these `NSArray` objects to a single `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Thanks @Midhun, it works, but I wouldn't know the value of the key coming in. Like 6: 00PM etc. Is there any way I can refer to that?

Comment: @anuragbh -- You need to decide what your "target" data structure is and work toward that, rather than just tossing the data around and hoping it lands in a form that will suit you.  THINK about how the data must be organized to do whatever it is you ultimately intend to do with the data.

Comment: @anuragbh: then only give `result` in the above code, instead of `result.6: 00PM`. This will give you an array of arrays, those arrays will have the objects you want.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks I will return to this and organize and label the code better.

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks, that is what I had in object 3 before. I was not able to extract the arrays from it. But I think I have a lead from your answer. I will iterate over the array and get the values for the keys I need.

Answer (score 1):

You are redefining *int i* in your second *for* loop. Try something like

```
for(int j = 0; j < num_results; j++)
```

Comment: Thanks fixed it, but it didnt help me parse the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
[temp addObject:[obj objectAtIndex:i]]; // I take each object from previous array and save it in a temp array
```

This is useless motion.  You're effectively just copying the `obj` array to the `temp` array -- no value added.