# How can i parse following data in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, parsing

Hello i am working on web service base iPhone application but the problem is my client provide web service which is in following formate and i don't know how to parse it. i will appreciate for any help or anybody share their experience.

> {"message":"[{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"DAMIN_V\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"DAMIN\",\"START_DATE\":\"04/04/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"
>   \",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"HLAD\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"James\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"DAMIN_V\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"DAMIN\",\"START_DATE\":\"06/01/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"
>   \",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"LucyE\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"Lucy\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"HLAD\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"James\",\"START_DATE\":\"04/16/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"
>   \",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"HT\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"HTx\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"HLAD\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"James\",\"START_DATE\":\"06/13/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"
>   \",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"SUPERMAN\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"james\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"MY
>   ORG USER\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"My ORG user
>   1\",\"START_DATE\":\"06/13/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"06/16/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"NFALPR1\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"Prince\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"PEK\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"Lucy
>   E\",\"START_DATE\":\"03/01/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"08/08/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"HRL\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"James\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"PNAIR\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"Carl\",\"START_DATE\":\"03/01/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"03/09/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"SCHITRE\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"Fun
>   bobby\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"LucyE\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"Lucy\",\"START_DATE\":\"03/01/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"03/31/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"HLAD\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"James\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"LucyE
>   E\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"Lucy\",\"START_DATE\":\"04/01/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"04/30/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"DAMIN_V\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"DAMIN\"},{\"APPROVER_ID\":\"LucyE
>   E\",\"APPROVER_USER_NAME\":\"Lucy\",\"START_DATE\":\"05/04/12\",\"END_DATE\":\"05/25/12\",\"SUBSTITUTE_ID\":\"JOSHIA\",\"SUBSTITUTE_USER_NAME\":\"Joye\"}]","statusFlag":true}

Thanks In Advance,
Nitin.

Comment: This looks like JSON to me. Refer to [this][1] to parse JSON.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jsonkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for json parsing.

Here is the code for the json kit library which is editing my simple class added and create one demo you can download the demo and easily identify the your problem

[Download the Demo from here.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nimitparekh/files/Webservice%20Calling/)

[Also refer the tutorial for the how to use json kit from here.](http://www.14oranges.com/2011/08/how-to-use-jsonkit-for-ios-and-the-rotten-tomatoes-api/)

Answer (score 2):

this is `JSON` data.
use `SBJSON.h` http://stig.github.com/json-framework/ to parse, which is light and easy