# Converting Unicode Returned by FB graph API to english

Tags: php, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am receiving unicode charactors in FB Graph requests for the user's name..
How can i convert it to english in iOS app ?
Also is anything like this available in PHP as well ?

Comment: Why would you try to convert unicode names to English ?

Comment: My iOS app is fetching FB name using the FB ID of the user.. FB is returning the name in unicode .. i have to display this name in game

Comment: Then display his name in Unicode, I would hate your app if my name had unicode characters and your app displayed my name in some foreign language that I am sure 100% will not be accurate.

Comment: \u9648\u73ab\u7af9  displaying this as name ? that can be done but i want to explore other options ..i know the locale is  "locale": "zh_CN" so how to display this in chinese characters or maybe some english equivalent name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer for this is to display his name in his language.

The best conversion It's coming into my mind is using `json_decode()`:

```
$name = '\u9648\u73ab\u7af9';
echo json_decode('"'.$name.'"');
// ouputs: 陈玫竹
```

I suggested `json_decode()` because it supports the `\uxxxx` syntax directly and other unicode or `utf-8` characters.

Comment: thanks dis works great for PHP .. im still exploring if smthing lyk dis in available in iOS as well ..

Comment: uhm, maibe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165290/how-to-parsing-json-object-in-iphone-sdk-xcode-using-json-framework) will help you getting same result in iOS.