# Is there a way to specify a specific object index in a valueForKeyPath statement?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, key-value

In calling NSDictionary valueForKeyPath if one level of the path is an array can you specify a specific element in the array?

For example:

```
[myDict valueForKeypath:@"customer.contactInfo.phoneNumbers[4].countryCode];
```

where .phoneNumbers is an NSArray. Or do I have to:

```
NSArray *numbers=[myDict valueForKeypath:@"customer.contactInfo.phoneNumbers];
NSString *countryCode=[[numbers objectAtIndex:4] objectForKey:@"countryCode"];
```

It would be really nice and much cleaner if this could be done in one statement.

Comment: Looks like the answer is "No": [Getting array elements with valueForKeyPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461126/getting-array-elements-with-valueforkeypath)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
NSString *myString = [[[myDict valueForKeypath:@"customer.contactInfo.phoneNumbers"] objectAtIndex:4] objectForKey:@"countryCode"];
```

Comment: It's in one statement, but still more verbose than directly accessing the array element.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a category I wrote for NSObject that can handle array indexes so you can access your nested object like this: "customer.contactInfo.phoneNumbers[4].countryCode"

```
@interface NSObject (ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes)
   -(id)valueForKeyPathWithIndexes:(NSString*)fullPath;
@end


#import "NSObject+ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes.h"    
@implementation NSObject (ValueForKeyPathWithIndexes)

-(id)valueForKeyPathWithIndexes:(NSString*)fullPath
{
    //quickly use standard valueForKeyPath if no arrays are found
    if ([fullPath rangeOfString:@"["].location == NSNotFound)
        return [self valueForKeyPath:fullPath];

    NSArray* parts = [fullPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    id currentObj = self;
    for (NSString* part in parts)
    {
        NSRange range = [part rangeOfString:@"["];
        if (range.location == NSNotFound)           
        {
            currentObj = [currentObj valueForKey:part];
        }
        else
        {
            NSString* arrayKey = [part substringToIndex:range.location];
            int index = [[[part substringToIndex:part.length-1] substringFromIndex:range1.location+1] intValue];
            currentObj = [[currentObj valueForKey:arrayKey] objectAtIndex:index];
        }
    }
    return currentObj;
}
@end
```

Use it like so

```
NSString* countryCode = [myDict valueForKeyPathWithIndexes:@"customer.contactInfo.phoneNumbers[4].countryCode"];
```

There's no error checking, so it's prone to breaking but you get the idea. I cross posted this answer to a similar (linked) question.