# How can I bind to NSTableColumn's headerTitle?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nstablecolumn

I would like to bind NSTableColumn's headerTitle property to an NSMutableArray in my model layer (via an NSArrayController).

Basically I want to have an array where I can change values and have the table column header titles update. Is that reasonable?

However, [the `headerTitle` binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableColumn.html#headerTitle) wants an single `NSString` and I'm not sure how to connect my model object to this binding via my `NSArrayController`. Google does not give many hits for this problem.

My model layer consists of two class (both of which are appropriately KVC compliant). The first is a model which represents a single column title, it has one property `title`,

```
// A model class representing the column title of single NSTableColumn
@interface ColumnTitle : NSObject
@property NSString *title;
+ (ColumnTitle*) columnTitleWithTitle:(NSString*) aString;
@end
```

The second a model object which represents an ordered group of ColumnTitle objects,

```
// Class representing an order collection of model items
@interface TableColumnTitles : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray* columnTitles;  // an array of ColumnTitle objects
// These are the KVC array accessors
-(void) insertObject:(ColumnTitle*)columnTitle inColumnTitlesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)removeObjectFromColumnTitlesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)replaceObjectInColumnTitlesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index withObject:(ColumnTitle*)columnTitle;
@end
```

Note that `TableColumnTitles` object implements the above array accessors which are required for the bindings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried that before but what you're actually asking for is using **KVC for array indexes**. A quick google didn't turn up anything on that issue except some results that indicate it's not (yet) possible (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461126/getting-array-elements-with-valueforkeypath))

The easiest work-around I could come up with would be to simply add dedicated properties for the array indexes.. not nice but does the job.

So for a `NSMutableArray` called `myArray` and contains objects with `title` properties of type `NSString` you'd do something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = columnOneGetter) NSString *columnOneString;

(NSString*) columnOneGetter
{
   return myArray[0].title;
}
```

Always assuming of course their number is known in advance and we're not talking 200 columns :-)

Comment: I'm just getting started with binds and I'm not sure how to go about implementing your idea. Could you explain in a bit more detail. Also, in general, how would you go about using the `NSTableColumn`'s `headerTitle` binding? Am I using it in an unusual way? I basically want to be able to set the table header titles by changing values in an array controller; it doesn't sound too controversial, but I can't find an example of how to do this anywhere!

Comment: Answer edited accordingly - usual disclaimer: typed into browser, not tested nor debugged, etc.

Comment: It does sound a bit weird to bind the current selection to the header, at least I can't come up with a use case where you'd want to change the header when the selected row in the table changes.

Comment: Actually I don't want to bind to the selection, that was just an example. The way I wrote the question is a bit confusing so sorry for that. I basically want to have a model `NSMutableArray` that I allows me to modify the header titles. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may/may not be what you're after, but quick google search landed me here:
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-add-touch-events-to-a-uitableviewfooter-or-header/

edit: i realize this is for mac (not ios) but should be pretty easy to translate if it actually helps.