# Can I invoke nsdictionary's valueForKeyPath when a key is an NSNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, key-value

I have an NSDictionary property called "optionsDictionary". One of the objects in that dictionary is nested dictionaries that hold scoring data for questions based on their answers. The key for that object is "score".

```
optionsDictionary = 
{
  "score":{
            6747:{
                   "a":"scoring data for answer 'a' to question with ID 6747"
                   "b":"scoring data for answer 'b' to question with ID 6747"
                 }
            3653:{
                   "a":"scoring data for answer 'a' to question with ID 3653"
                   "b":"scoring data for answer 'b' to question with ID 3653"
                 }
          }
}
```

I am trying to get scoring data by doing something like:

```
NSString* scoringData = [self.optionsDictionary valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"score.%@.%@",question.qID,question.qAnswer]];
```

I know this will work perfectly if all keys were strings, but the question ID keys (6747 and 3653) are NSNumbers. Can I still use valueForKeyPath with one of the keys along the path being an NSNumber?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you actually tried executing this code?

Comment: @akashg Not yet, just got this idea and I don't have access to a Mac  to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why r u using the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol method?!?!

U better try using `NSDictionary` method:

```
objectForKey:
```

Try to get `NSDictionary` key as a string, like:

```
NSDictionary* scoringData = self.optionsDictionary[@"score"];
```

By the way, your JSON is NOT a valid, u better add , (comma) between each key-value object (json) and gather 2 or more jsons into array []:

```
{
  "optionsDictionary" : 
  {
    "score":{
              "6747":[
                     "a":"scoring data for answer 'a' to question with ID 6747",
                     "b":"scoring data for answer 'b' to question with ID 6747"
                  ],
              "3653":[
                     "a":"scoring data for answer 'a' to question with ID 3653",
                     "b":"scoring data for answer 'b' to question with ID 3653"
                   ]
            }
  }
}
```

Comment: The JSON was only intended to illustrate the structure I am talking about. Sorry I didn't make that clear in the original post.

Comment: Cheers! Does my answer helped u?

Comment: It sure did! I understand I can use objectForKey to achieve what I want to do. But do you know if I can use key-value as well?

Comment: See this m8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461126/getting-array-elements-with-valueforkeypath

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept my answer. 10x m8!

Answer (score 1):

What about the following, which will work as long as the types used in the subscripting matches the keys of each dictionary:

```
NSString *scoringData = self.optionsDictionary[question][qID][question.qAnswer];
```